# Powershell exporting function verbose messages

Tags: powershell, scripting, verbose

This is the start of a script I'm working on:

```
#Requires –Version 4.0

$DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Import-Module UMF

#region Synchronized Collections

$FormHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$RunspaceHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Jobs = [system.collections.arraylist]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))
$JobCleanup = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

#endregion

#region Pre-Startup Checks

$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
Write-Log Verbose Info 'Pre-startup checks started...'
```

When I start this, I get this in my console:

> ```
> VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-FileHash'.
> VERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-TemporaryFile'.
> VERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-Guid'.
> VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Format-Hex'.
> VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'fhx'.
> VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Import-PowerShellDataFile'.
> VERBOSE: Exporting function 'ConvertFrom-SddlString'
> VERBOSE: 2015-12-19 17:44:18,227: Info: Pre-startup checks started...
> ```

So why does it show this 'Exporting function' Verbose messages while I explicitly set VerbosePreference to SilentlyContinue?

The Module UMF contains only one function and that is `Write-Log`.

Comment: I'm not sure how but it seems I'm no longer seeing these export logs, although I'm still using 'Import-Module UMF'

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior when setting $VerbosePreference to Continue, but only when I start such script by powershell.exe -F "Script.ps1" Parameter. When I start it manual or in PowerShell ISE, there is no Verbose-Message with Exporting function etc.